# Cannot resolve dns on 12.10 install

Tags: 12.10, wireless, networking, dns, resolv.conf

I am very new to networking on Ubuntu so I have been struggling with this issue for several hours now. I am running a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10 and I am unable to resolve DNS when using my wireless connection. I have followed many of the solutions I found through some Googling but still can't get it to work. I tried adding the Google name servers to `/etc/resolv.conf` but that didn't help. I also tried adding static name servers through the network manager and that was unsuccessful as well. I get the following when I enter `ifcongig -a` on the command line.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:2d:7f:ea:7c  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:247 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:247 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:22898 (22.8 KB)  TX bytes:22898 (22.8 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:1a:04:e9:3a:4b  
          inet addr:10.0.0.28  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::721a:4ff:fee9:3a4b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:121 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:403 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:41374 (41.3 KB)  TX bytes:38438 (38.4 KB)
```

My `/etc/resolv.conf` currently looks like this:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

And on doing `dig google.com` I get:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

On `ping -c 10 8.8.8.8`, I get:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.28 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.28 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.28 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.28 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.28 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.28 icmp_seq=7 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.28 icmp_seq=8 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.28 icmp_seq=10 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 received, +8 errors, 100% packet loss, time 8999ms
pipe 4
```

Here is my output for `sudo route -n`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
```

And my output for `traceroute -n 8.8.8.8`:

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.0.0.28  1804.234 ms !H  1804.210 ms !H  1804.199 ms !H
```

I would also like to note that I am able to connect to the wireless network on my other devices and on my Windows installation on the same machine. I also am able to get on the web when I connect through ethernet.

I get this snippet for the wireless connection when I do `ipconfig` on my windows machine:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : hsd1.ma.comcast.net.
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Atheros AR5B93 Wireless Network Adapter
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 70-1A-04-E9-3A-4B
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b153:23b2:2384:d341%12(Preferred)
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.28(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, May 09, 2013 1:50:10 PM
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, May 16, 2013 3:39:12 PM
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 225450500
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-17-D9-81-3A-00-26-2D-7F-EA-7C

DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 75.75.75.75
                                   75.75.76.76
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated since this is really frustrating.

Comment: Hi! Could you please update your question adding the contents of /etc/resolv.conf, and also from running this on a terminal to see where it is trying to resolve? `dig google.com`

Comment: I have added the information you requested. Thanks!

Comment: Hey! sorry, to rule out a routing/networking problem, could you also paste output of the `route` command, and `ping -c 10 8.8.8.8` to confirm whether you can reach Google's DNS? Thanks!

Comment: I just added my result for `ping -c 10 8.8.8.8` to the original post and it seems like it's unreachable.

Comment: Thanks, so as the below answer mentions this looks like a deeper network problem. Could you please post output of `route -n` and `traceroute -n 8.8.8.8`? This will show whether it's a problem with the local routing table or with the router which maybe can't reach the outside.

Comment: Thanks!the routes look OK, but the `!H` in your traceroute output means a "host unreachable". 10.0.0.28 is your local IP address and what this means is you can't reach the router, even though the routes seem fine. Can you ping the router (10.0.0.1)?

Comment: I pinged 10.0.0.1 and it also says "Destination Host Unreachable."

Comment: I ended up moving out of that apartment and I haven't had network problems since. It's either something to do with Comcast or the way the router was set up. Either way, thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Your /etc/resolv.conf appears correct.  This appears to be a network issue, not a DNS one.

Try taking your eth0 down (some of the GUI network managers prefer wired connections over wireless, and it may think you have a signal for some strange reason).  The command to take it down would be "sudo ifdown eth0" and then try to dig google.com.  Alternately, if Ubuntu took the ifdown scripts away (don't know whether they did or not) you can do "sudo ifconfig eth0 down".

If you want to bring it back up, just do "sudo ifup eth0" or "sudo ifconfig eth0 up".

Comment: I tried `sudo ifdown eth0` and I get the following error message: `ifdown: interface eth0 not configured`. So I resorted to `sudo ifconfig eth0 down` but `dig google.com` still returns the same result as stated in my post.

Comment: Okay, a copy of the output of `sudo route` would help, that'll show us where your traffic is going, because it appears you don't have any internet access not just a DNS problem.  Just to make sure, other devices connected to the wifi do have internet access correct? I know that I've moved my stuff around before and forgotten to plug my modem back in a couple times.

Comment: I am able to connect to the wireless network on my other devices and also on my windows installation on the same machine. I also do not have this issue when connected through ethernet. I have updated my post with the requested information. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, your route looks wrong.  Did you set any of that up?  Unless Ubuntu displays things differently, you should have a route in there that looks like "10.0.0.28 * *" and then some other stuff.  It looks like your router might be pushing route settings that don't work with Ubuntu, which is fine, we can fix that, we just need to figure out what to do with it.  Try `sudo route add 10.0.0.28 dev wlan0`

Comment: @Seth: sorry, but the routes look OK, he doesn't need a static route to 10.0.0.28 which is the local IP address. Also, the asterisks (*) signifying the 0.0.0.0 (default) network don't show because I asked him to use the `-n` switch to get faster output.

Comment: Crap, you're right.  Usually I only look at things this hard on virtual guests using failovers on another subnet which gets all kind of weird. 10.0.0.1 is your gateway address correct?  The IP of your router?  Also, just as a side note, any idea where that 169.254.0.0/16 entry coming from?  Is that where your traffic should be going? I guess I should just ask, what is your router's IP, and what IP's do your other PC's have?  (Just a range, don't need an exact number) and can you ping any of your other PC's?

Comment: I have added my output for `ipconfig` from my windows installation to the post.  From whatismyip.com, my ip address is 76.118.181.160 which is different from that shown on the output. I guess this is where  "local" ip comes into play. unfortunately I can't run windows and ubuntu simultaneously since they are on the same machine. So I can't do a ping until I my roommate gets back and I can try to ping his pc. In any case, how would I ping his pc? I'm guessing something like <computername>@localip?

Comment: I just wanted to add that I just went to a friend's place who uses verizon and was able to connect to the web using his wireless connection. It looks like this is specific to my router or my comcast set up. I don't know how to even begin debugging this.

Comment: Is that the Windows machine on the same computer?  I only ask because the IP address is the same, which would be a problem if they were two separate computers.  If it's the same computer, that's normal though.  Perhaps try manually running `dhclient eth0` to see if you can force a new IP?  Perhaps there's something odd happening with the Windows/Ubuntu crossover.  Also, let us know whether you can ping another PC on the same LAN, because the only things I can think of right now would be your wifi settings are bad, or Comcast is blocking Google's DNS.  Try setting your DNS to those in the pic.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to let ubuntu manage DNS automatically for you?

In short: using "resolvconf"

```
sudo apt-get install resolvconf
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

reference:

[Auto DNS resolving in Ubuntu 12.04 desktop](http://oct.im/2013/05/auto-dns-resolving-in-ubuntu-12-04-desktop/)