# Ubuntu 14.04 - Network problems (wireless and DNS)

Tags: wireless, 14.04, networking, dns

I have seen a very similar problem on post: [Cannot resolve dns on 12.10 install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292622/cannot-resolve-dns-on-12-10-install) but with no clear answer and my problem is related to Ubuntu 14.04, another particularity is that this problem started without any configuration change made by me.

Also, I can connect from any other device to my computer through SSH or SAMBA but I cannot ping or do anything from the Ubuntu to my other devices (win7)

Here goes some information

`route -n`

```
Kernel IP routing table

Destination      Gateway      Genmask      Flags      Metric      Ref      Use Iface

0.0.0.0                  192.168.0.1      0.0.0.0      UG      0      0      0      wlan0

192.168.0.0      0.0.0.0      255.255.255.0      U      9      0      0      wlan0

192.168.2.0      0.0.0.0      255.255.255.0      U      0      0      0      vmnet8

192.168.180.0      0.0.0.0      255.255.255.0      U      0      0      0      vmnet1
```

`/etc/resolv.conf`

```
"# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)

"#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

nameserver 127.0.1.1

search spo.virtua.com.br
```

As per my version of Ubuntu I understand that resolv.conf is auto configured by resolvconf and I created /etc/resolvconf.conf to try to force some extra configuration

`/etc/resolvconf.conf`

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8

nameserver 192.168.0.1

nameserver 127.0.0.1

nameserver 127.0.1.1

search spo.virtua.com.br
```

`dig google.com`

```
; > DiG 9.9.5-3-Ubuntu > google.com

;; global options: +cmd

;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Pinging 8.8.8.8 (Google)

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---

17 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 16126ms
```

Pinging my router

```
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C

--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---

9 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 8063ms
```

Traceroute my router

```
traceroute: unknown host 192.168.0.1
```

Does anyone know what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Since not even ping to your router works, no need to look for DNS problems first. 1) Are you sure your router is 192.168.0.1? 2) What does ifconfig give you?